# Convert .xliff files to Excel or Google Sheets

Tags: ios, swift, google-sheets, localization, xliff

My app is relatively simple, and I am localizing it to multiple new languages. The Xcode's editor for .xliff and .xclok files is really convenient because it presents all fields in a table.

However, since I am using Google Translate anyway (the app is simple enough that its decent), I envision the fastest way to localize the app into endless number of languages is to export the .xliff file into Google Sheets and use the built in translate function to translate the whole app in one click. Basically I want the same table format as the Xcode's .xclok editor, but in google sheets so I could process the text instantly.

Is that doable?

Comment: You can use deepl to translate xliff files https://support.deepl.com/hc/en-us/articles/7507376697500-Translation-of-XLIFF-files